# Angular2 rxjs filter double click Property 'length' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm 
just playing around with Rxjs

what's wrong with this code

I've got an error

my goal is to set the 'My message'

only when the button is clicked twice.

### Property 'length' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent'.

//JS

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  message = 'Hello Rxjs';
  @ViewChild('btn') btn: ElementRef;
  ngOnInit(){
    let clicks = Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.getNativeElement(this.btn), 'click')
    .filter(ev => ev.length >= 2)
    .map(e => 'My Message')
    .subscribe(msg => this.message = msg);
  }
  getNativeElement(element){
    return element.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

//html

```
<h1>
  <button #btn>Click</button>
  {{message}}
</h1>
```

UPDATE1

I'm following this course 
courses.ultimateangular.com
and the problem 
happens with the other snippet :(

UPDATE2
following the hint of @martin
this seems to work

```
let clicks = Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.getNativeElement(this.btn), 'click')
    .bufferCount(2, 1)
    .map(e => 'ah Pippo')
    .subscribe(msg => this.message = msg);
```

Comment: (try `(<MouseEvent>ev)` instead of ev. I want to see if the type is getting output.

Comment: @vitiral Argument of type 'MouseEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: MouseEvent, index: number) => boolean'.
  Type 'MouseEvent' provides no match for the signature '(value: MouseEvent, index: number): boolean'

Comment: it looks like `ev` is not actulaly an event -- it is a function. Otherwise, I'm not sure what the problem is, sorry!

Comment: @Whisher event `MouseEvent` really doesn't have property `length`. Btw, what's length of a mouse event? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

Comment: @martin yeah you agree but in this example of version 4 there is http://jsfiddle.net/staltz/4gGgs/27/ but may I misunderstanding because I can see now there is buffer before.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to accept only two mouse events and then complete use [`take()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-take) operator:

```
let clicks = Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.getNativeElement(this.btn), 'click')
  .take(2)
  .map(e => 'My Message')
  .subscribe(msg => this.message = msg);
```

Comment: It doesn't work I can see the message with only a click

Comment: I've update the thread using bufferCount(2, 1) and it seems to work what do you think about ?

Comment: `.take(2)` takes 2 values and calls onComplete callback. So if you want to collect the two values and then call onNext `.take(2).toArray()` that gives you an array of values collected. Operator `bufferCount(2)` will call the onNext callback multiple times. I don't know if this is what you want.